# checking type of reference in generics java

Tags: java, generics, types, reference, instanceof

I am currently building a game in java(turn based RPG) and am facing a problem in inventory UI. Perhaps my problem is well known or has a simple solution, but having never had any training, I will still ask the question.

While displaying the inventory after selecting an item I check if that item implements the `SpecificItemWorker` interface , that is, acts on a specific `GameObject` that has to be passed in to its `takeAction()` method. While selecting that object which has to be passed, I display all the possible candidate objects for the user to select. For example, suppose the user selects a `UpgradeParchment` that acts on any object that implements `Upgradable` interface. Here, I initiate a `ItemSelector` that displays all the items in the inventory that implements `Upgradable`. However with a different class , the interface that the object needs to implement in order to be a possible candidate will differ.(Note that some objects act on the game environment rather than on a specific object, but we are not considering that case here.).Now instead of hard-coding the possible interfaces in a `switch case` statement , i want it to be dynamic.I tried to use generics, but it does not allow to check if an object is an `instanceof` of the Type parameter.
The following code gives a compile error:

```
package ui;

import objects.Collectable;

public class ItemSelector<T> {
    public void test(Collectable ob) {
        if (ob instanceof T) {// compile error
            // do work
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how this can be achieved?Thanks for any help.

Looking for a speedy reply, 
Thanks.

**EDIT :**
The parameter in the `testAction()` method will be of type `Collectable` as in my inventory class, there is only a list of `Collectable` objects.Similarly, in my test method , I have updated the types.Although it is a minor change, sorry for any inconvenience.`Collectable` is also an interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to runtime type erasure, you need to provide what's called a *type token* to the class:

```
public class ItemSelector<T> {
    private final Class<T> clazz;
    public ItemSelector(Class<T> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    public void test(GameObject ob) {
        if (clazz.isInstance(ob)) {// use token to check type
            // do work
        }
    }
}
```

This requires a class object to be passed to the constructor, usually by passing a class literal, eg `MyClass.class`

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to check the type with class.getTypeName().

I assume the SpecificItemWorker is a game object as shown in the code.

```
package stackoverflow.question39718130;

public class SpecificItemWorker extends GameObject {
}
```

---

```
package stackoverflow.question39718130;

public class ItemSelector<T> {

    private T t;

    public ItemSelector(final T t) {
        this.t = t;
    }

    public T getT() {
        return t;
    }

    public void test(final GameObject ob) {
        /*if (ob instanceof T) {// compile error
            // do work
        }*/

        if (t.getClass().getTypeName() == ob.getClass().getTypeName()) {
            System.out.println("Grab item.");
        } else {
            System.err.println("No item found.");
        }
    }
}
```

---

There is a test example to pass the `GameObject`.

```
package stackoverflow.question39718130;

public class GameObjectTest {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        specificItemWorkerTest();
    }

    public static void specificItemWorkerTest() {
        final GameObject specificItemWorker = new SpecificItemWorker();

        final ItemSelector<GameObject> selector = new ItemSelector<>(specificItemWorker);
        selector.test(specificItemWorker);
    }
}
```

I hope I understood you right with the `SpecificItemWorker`. Please let me know if this fits to your solution.

Comment: The `class.getTypeName()` method returns information about the class type.But it cannot be used to pass the IS-A relationship test.Also , `SpecificItemWorker` is an interface. It is used to decide whether the object the user selects to use needs another `Collectable` object to work on.

Comment: This incorrect on multiple levels, but especially using `==` to compare Strings, which will never be true